# The probability that the equation will have real roots is

Tags: probability

Each coefficient in equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is determined by throwing an ordinary die. What is the probability that the equation will have real roots?

How do I go about doing this? Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please avoid dropping your questions on us. What have you tried? where did you get stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by an ordinary die? so the numbers $a,b$ and $c$ can only take values between $1$ and $6$?

Comment: @OveAhlman i think so.

Comment: The solution of a quadratic equation is given by $x = \frac{-b +/- \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ so as long as the determinant $b^2 - 4ac$ is positive, there will be a solution to the equation. All that is left is to count the possibilities.

Comment: To fnd the roots there is a formula with a square root. This square root must be greater or equal than zero.

Comment: [Another dup candidate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617695)

Answer (score 1):

To have solutions, the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ must be positive. To count how many possibilities of $216$ total there are such that $b^2-4ac$ is not positive, we can just try them all. A simple Mathematica script:

```
r = 0;
For[a = 1, a <= 6, a++,
  For[b = 1, b <= 6, b++,
    For[c = 1, c <= 6, c++,
      If[b^2 - 4*a*c < 0, r++];
    ];
  ];
];
r/(6^3)
```

Results in $\frac{173}{216}$, which is about $0.8009\ldots$ (that's the chance that the equation is *not* solvable).

Comment: Playing with icosahedrons instead of cubes, we would get $\frac{3067}{4000}=0.76675$ ! Using disdyakis triacontahedrons $\frac{215993}{288000}\approx  0.75000$. Funny !